# Breakpoints don't hit on CLion

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion

I am using CLion and for some reason the breakpoints don't work at all.

I tried to go to 'Build, Execution, Deployment' and change the build configuration but it is already set to Debug, as you can see:

[image: Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake configuration]

Also I saw some suggestions to add `SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` or `SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-D_DEBUG")` but none of them mentions where :(

I tried to put it in the CMakeLists.txt but it didn't help

Also tried to reset caches and restart with no success.

Comment: It is never the right answer to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @AlexReinking do you know maybe what can help?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with the same issue:

what worked for me was deleting all the CMake output files (mainly the generated files in the `cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/projectName.dir` directory)